# Uploading image [Cypress]

Tags: automation, image-uploading, cypress

I'm trying to upload a jpeg image from **local files** to a webpage developed here in my job. The thing is, we need to click on the page to **open the file explorer** and then select the image (or drag and drop into the same spot that may be clicked).
[Here is a picture from the web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J450d.png)

I don't know how could i do that, i was trying some code that i've seen in "https://medium.com/@chrisbautistaaa/adding-image-fixtures-in-cypress-a88787daac9c". But don't worked. I actually don't know how it works exactly, could anyone help me?

[Here is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDkqP.png)

After @brendan's help, I was able to solve the problem by finding an input that was "hidden" under an element. However, before that I tried drag-n-drop, and cypress returned me an error (despite the successful upload). The context was, immediately after the upload, the element re-renders and cypress told me that:
 [image: and cypress told me that].

Beside the success with input element, i was wondering how it would be possible to resolve this error, is it possible to do something internally to cypress to ignore or wait until the element re-renders back to normal?
Solutions suggested by cypress:

[image: Solutions suggested by cypress]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're doing this using [cypress-file-upload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-file-upload)

Here's an example from our code:

```
cy.fixture(fileName).then(fileContent => {
  cy.get(selectors.dropZoneInput).upload(
    { fileContent, fileName, mimeType: "application/pdf" },
    { subjectType: "drag-n-drop" }
  );
});
```

For your purpose, I think this will work:

```
cy.fixture(imagePath).then(fileContent => {
  cy.get(".upload-box").first().upload(
    { fileContent, fileName, mimeType: "image/jpeg" },
    { subjectType: "drag-n-drop" }
  );
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to solve the problem by finding an input that was "hidden" under an element. However, before that I tried drag-n-drop, and immediately after the successfully upload, the element re-renders and cypress told me that: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPFTN.png

How it would be possible to solve this error, maybe something internally to cypress to ignore or wait until the element re-renders back to normal?
Solutions suggested by cypress: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgNI5.png

Comment: As they suggest, you can use `cy.wait()` to wait for an XHR that triggers the rerender if there is one, then use `cy.get()` again to get the fresh element